# Image scraper using Dependecy Injection in Rust with generics

Tags: design-patterns, rust, dependency-injection

I'm writing a scraper that downloads images from a given subreddit. I'm new to Rust, and in the majority of my previous projects I was using C++ or Java, where it's easy to do Dependency Injection.

I wanted to use DI in this project, so I could inject a mock service for tests, and because *I think that's how it's supposed to be done* - but maybe that's not the case, and one should use a totally different design pattern in Rust?

My code (I'm on an early stage of development):

`reddit_service.rs`:

```
pub trait RedditService {
    fn get_next_urls(self) -> Vec<String>;

    fn from_new() -> Self;

    fn get_one_url(self) -> String;
}

pub struct MockRedditService {}

impl RedditService for MockRedditService {
    fn get_next_urls(self) -> Vec<String> {
        Vec::new()
    }

    fn from_new() -> MockRedditService {
        MockRedditService {}
    }

    fn get_one_url(self) -> String {
        String::from("example url")
    }
}
```

`manager.rs`:

```
use super::reddit_service::RedditService;

pub struct Manager<RS> {
    reddit_service: RS,
}

impl<RS: RedditService> Manager<RS> {
    pub fn new(reddit_service: RS) -> Manager<RS> {
        Manager { reddit_service }
    }

    pub fn scrap(self, subreddit: &str, limit: u32) -> () {
        println!("Scrapping {} images from {}", limit, subreddit);
        println!("Scrapped: {}", self.reddit_service.get_one_url())
    }
}
```

and in `main.rs`:

```
let app_manager = Manager::<MockRedditService>::new(MockRedditService::from_new());
app_manager.scrap(subreddit, limit);
```

My two questions are:

1. is that how DI is supposed to be done in Rust? (I've also read about using `Box<dyn Trait>`, but I didn't like it)
2. is the DI even useful here? Maybe there's a better way of achieving clean code, which is easy to test, without using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that how DI is supposed to be done in Rust?

The core concept of dependency injection is: don't make your data/service dependencies hard-coded, but provide some way for the caller/configuration to provide an alternative. You've identified two ways to do it — trait objects and generics, both of which start with a trait, i.e. polymorphism — and those are both fine but you don't necessarily need to use polymorphism to do dependency injection.

In particular, since your application is a kind of network client, one straightforward approach to testing is to *direct your client to connect to a different server* (in particular, one that you started up locally, that pretends to be Reddit). Thus, instead of providing a different type of implementation of `RedditService`, you provide a different *server address.*

Advantages of using a local server for testing:

- The client code is not constrained by needing to pass through the specific `RedditService` interface you designed — it can be structured however is convenient for its actual job, and refactoring that structure does not require modifying the tests.
- You are exercising *more of the stack* — not just your scraping logic, but also the HTTP client you use. When writing mocks of the interfaces between individual “objects”, it can be very easy to write a test that technically has 100% code coverage, but is not actually useful because the behavior of the mock does not accurately represent the behavior of the real subsystem it's meant to imitate.

Disadvantages:

- Writing a test-double server probably requires providing more fake data and other API details than implementing `RedditService`.
- You're testing a larger unit of code, so it's harder to nail down exactly where a failure is.

---

Now, commentary on your actual code:

```rust
pub trait RedditService {
    ...
    fn from_new() -> Self;
```

- Such a constructor is usually called `new()`, not `from_new()`.
- It is often not a great idea to include zero-argument constructors like this in traits. By including it, you're *requiring that every implementation can be constructed from zero information*, which is a bad idea especially for a network client:

  - The real implementation should probably be constructed with some configuration (server address, throttling policy, `User-Agent` string, etc.)
  - The mock implementation should probably be constructed with some test data.
    So, remove this method entirely, and just let each individual implementation have an inherent `new()` that takes whatever parameters are useful.

  (In cases where a zero-argument constructor makes sense, consider using the standard library's `Default` trait for that purpose.)

```rust
    fn get_next_urls(self) -> Vec<String>;
    fn get_one_url(self) -> String;
```

These two methods take `self` *by value*, meaning that once you call them you can't use the value you called them on any more. They should probably take a reference instead:

```
    fn get_next_urls(&mut self) -> Vec<String>;
    fn get_one_url(&mut self) -> String;
```

This isn't a matter of style, though: it's something that you will find you need to change one way or another to make your code *actually work.*

```
    pub fn scrap(self, subreddit: &str, limit: u32) -> () {
```

`-> ()` is the *default* return type; you can leave those symbols out entirely. The Rust toolchain includes a linter that will tell you things like this: run `cargo clippy` and see what it says. Clippy lints (as opposed to compiler built-in lints) are not always good ideas; they're deliberately more ambitious and more likely wrong than compiler lints. However, they are designed to tell you about a lot of possible issues that you can run into a beginner, so I recommend reading what they have to say.

---

Finally, a point of English rather than Rust: The tool you're writing is a *scraper* to *scrape* Reddit, not a *scrapper* to *scrap* Reddit. They are both standard English words but they mean different things.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I realized that my code has some of the issues you've mentioned -- but your answer provided very useful insight too